# Distributed environment

Tags: jmeter

I had setup a distributed environment with one master and five slaves. When I am performing an operation of consuming an API service, I am unable to get results. In single machine environment getting expected result.

Will anyone please guide me or provide me some references so that I can proceed further.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide more information about your question in order to let other users to help you.

Comment: @LucianoRodríguez I have a set up of 1 mater and 5 slaves. In my test plan , have a Http request to be load tested. Through jmeter server client , am able to run the load in distributed way but the result which need to be captured in master machine  i.e; as view tree is not showing up . Using a Ubuntu version of OS systems with 8 GBB RAMS and Jmeter version is 2.11.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are getting proper response in Summary Report or Aggregate report listeners (***distributed environment***), change the following settings in Master Jmeter.properties file:

***Remote batching configuration***

Change "**#mode=Standard**" to "***mode=Standard***"

Otherwise if you are not getting response in Summary Report or Aggregate report listeners as well, then make sure that both Master & Slaves are in same network subnet.

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable solution. However i am still not getting the results in distributed environment .

Comment: Do you get any data in the Summary report listener in distributed environment??

Comment: No , we have tried with most of the listeners and could not get the results . Even we tried for logging the results in csv and no success with it as well.

Comment: Then I believe the issue is that the Master and Slaves are in different network. All the servers should be in same IP range e.g. 10.19.1.1 (Master), 10.19.1.2 (Slave), 10.19.1.3 (Slave)..... and so on